# Regular Expression Grouping

Tags: objective-c, regex

The language I am programming in is Objective C, although that probably has no bearing on solving this problem.

Given 0 to 3 occurrences of `6, 7, 9, 11 and 13` along with their modifiers `b` or `#`, how would you write a regex so that you can retrieve the groupings for each value? Is regex even the best solution here? Here's are some examples of some strings that need to be matched:

```
Example 1: 7#9  //The groupings should be 7 #9

Example 2: 7b9#13 //The groupings should be 7 b9 #13

Example 3: b6 //The grouping should be b6

Example 4: 7#1311 //The groupings should be 7 #13 11

Example 5: 7911 //The groupings should be 7 9 11
```

To match just one number like #13, I tried the following:

```
([#b]?13|11|9|7|6)?
```

It matches for #13, but not for #11. I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was that the [#|b] set was not being applied to 13, 11, 9, 7 and 6 individually. Also, I duplicated it to handle multiple groupings. Here's the fix:

```
([b#]?13|[b#]?11|[b#]?9|[b#]?7|[b#]?6)?([b#]?13|[b#]?11|[b#]?9|[b#]?7|[b#]?6)?([b#]?13|[b#]?11|[b#]?9|[b#]?7|[b#]?6)?([b#]?13|[b#]?11|[b#]?9|[b#]?7|[b#]?6)?
```

For string `b9#1113` it now groups as follows:

Group 1: b9 
Group 2: #11 
Group 3: 13

Answer (score 0):

You misplaced the parenthesis. The **answer** should be this:

> [#b]?(13|11|9|7|6)

Where it looks for the combination of each number with a possible #b

instead of

> ([#b]?13|11|9|7|6)?

where it only looks for the combination of #13 or 11 or 9 .. etc

Comment: Yeah, I tried a solution like that as well. The only problem is the matching. For `#139`, for example, it creates 4 groups: `#13`, `13`, `9` and `9`. How am I to distinguish between the groups I want and the groups I do not want?

Comment: I updated my answer. Note that I removed the last "?" Because it also looks for zero-lenght-matches which means that always an extra group was created even if there was no match with your regex

Comment: Hmmm....it still fails for #13, 9#11, etc. Take a look: https://regex101.com/r/nJ1dP6/1